# Listview is empty after OnResume in android

Tags: android, android-listview, onresume, android-lifecycle, onpause

In android , after lock and unlock the mobile, the activity get pause and resumed. On that time listview become empty.Pls help me to save values in onPause and retrieve that in onResume...

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you looked at the Android Notepad tutorial? Steps 3-8 cover saving and restoring instance state.

http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/notepad/notepad-ex3.html

Comment: Hi thanks for ur comment...actually i want to save the Arraylist(which fill listview) in onPause and Retrive that in onResume... thanks again

Answer (score 2):

Try putting the contents into the listview in `onResume()` instead of your `onCreate()` or some other method. Or even saving the instance is an option as @Drooling_Sheep said.

Comment: Hi thanks for ur answer...actually i want to save the Arraylist(which fill listview) in onPause and Retrive that in onResume .... Thanks again